# Get Param value to insert listing dataprovider

Tags: data-provider, insertlisting

Hello I have form with grid, it call insert listing. I check param value, but still I see NULL. I dont know why get this value. Anybody who can help me?
[image]

adminreporty_data_form.xml

```
<insertListing name="adminreporty_data_detail">
        <settings>
            <dataLinks>
                <exports>false</exports>
                <imports>true</imports>
            </dataLinks>
            <externalProvider>adminreporty_data_detail.adminreporty_zasilky_grid_data_source</externalProvider>
            <autoRender>true</autoRender>
            <dataScope>adminreporty_data_detail</dataScope>
            <ns>adminreporty_data_detail</ns>
            <exports>
                <link name="id">${ $.externalProvider }:params.id</link>
            </exports>
            <imports>
                <link name="id">${ $.provider }:data.id</link>
            </imports>
        </settings>
    </insertListing>
```

adminreporty_data_detail.xml

```
<dataSource name="adminreporty_zasilky_grid_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Dawe\AdminReporty\Ui\DataProvider\ListingZasilky</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">adminreporty_zasilky_grid_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Dataprovider ListingZasilky.php

```
public function getData()
{
    //$id = $this->request->getParam('id');
    //var_dump($id); die();
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    $data = $collection->toArray();
    return $data;
   
}
```

Comment: Ok, I find solution. It was problem on form dataprovider it send no data.

Comment: PLease post the answer if you want. It will help to other

Comment: @DavidSynek i am facing the same issue like you faced, Can you please provide your approach as an answer?

Comment: @DavidSynek you may check my question here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363746/how-to-show-data-in-grid-based-on-url-parameter-in-magento-2-custom-form